# Query Firebase Javascript By Key Value Not Working

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to filter my Firebase data by "City" however I am getting no JSON in return... my structure is like this when I imported JSON...

```
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "Goroka Airport",
        "City": "Goroka"
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "Name": "Madang Airport",
        "City": "Madang"
    }
]
```

My Javascript below... returns nothing

```
var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://URL-apps.firebaseio.com/airports");

myFirebaseRef.orderByChild('City').equalTo('Goroka').on("value",function(snapshot) { 
    var data = snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(child.val()));

    }); 
});
```

Firebase Database Layout (Collapsed) -- each airport is a node under "Airports" 0..1..etc

[image: Firebase Database Layout Collapsed]

Firebase Database Layout (Expanded)

[image: Firebase Database Layout]

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/wesoju/edit?js,console. Note that my jsbin uses the newer Firebase SDK, which I recommend you upgrade to anyway.

Comment: Interesting, the SDK I had in JSFiddle was extremely outdated. Thank you Frank!

Answer (score 0):

Your myFirebaseRef needs to be something like this:

```
var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://URL-apps.firebaseio.com/airports").database().ref();
```

Comment: Tried that, no change... nothing returned. I added full firebase URL to my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

SDK was using 1.0, Franks code above worked with FB JS Client SDK 4.0

```
var config = {
 databaseURL: "https://URL-apps.firebaseio.com/",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var ref = firebase.database().ref("/airports");


ref.orderByChild('City').equalTo('Goroka').on("value",function(snapshot) { 
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(child.val()));
    }); 
});
```